# How to say in different/ better way?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-order, word-in-context

I have completed the certification program, but after 24h I do not have the badge yet?
Can you assist?

Is is correct word formation and can I express my thoughts in better more natural American language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be an improvement to phrase your sentence slightly differently:

> I have completed the certification program but not yet received the certificate that I expected within 24 hours. May I ask you kindly to follow this up?

The expression **can you assist** is perfectly correct. My phraseology is just a little more polite.

The phrase **but after 24 hours** can easily be understood in context to mean 24 hours after completion of the program but it's not idiomatic in this sentence.

The word **badge** would indicate either an object made of cloth or metal that would be attached to a garment or similar.

If the acknowledgement you expect is a document, the word **certificate** is appropriate.

If you merely expected **confirmation**, then say so.

If you actually expect a badge, change my suggested wording accordingly.